# pocketsphinx python give wrong timestamp

Tags: python, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am using pocketsphinx to convert audio into text. It works fine. Now I want to get timestamp of each word. This is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
framerate = 100
with sr.AudioFile("1.wav") as source:

    audio = r.record(source)

    decoder = r.recognize_sphinx(audio, show_all=False)

    print ([(seg.word, seg.start_frame/framerate)for seg in decoder.seg()])
```

According to their documentation, the default framerate is 100. I got the starting time of each word. However, it is incorrect. The difference is 2 seconds, sometimes more than 3 seconds.

It is known issue or Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that the rate was `1/100` So, with my project I divided by, on accident, `1/10` instead of `1/100` but the results were actually fine for what I was doing. I would suggest dividing by `0.1` or `0.01` and see what that provides you.

So for your code just try out those variables:

```
framerate = .1
```

OR

```
framerate = .01
```

Comment: it doesn't make much sense, because if the framerate is 100 by default, you have to divide the time you get by 100, not other numbers. So if he sets framerate to those values the result is completely wrong